# "M coord limit exceeded" error when clippling line to polygon (ArcMap 10.5)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, clip, topology, error-999999

I am running ArcGIS Desktop 10.5.1, and am trying to clip a large line feature (stream) using a single polygon extracted from a larger polygon layer (taxmap). Keep getting "Error 999999: Error executing function." I have run this type of clip successfully multiple times before using these source layers, so I am rather stumped.

This is the error message readout:

> Invalid Topology [M coord limit exceeded.]
>
> Failed to execute (Clip).
>
> Failed at Wed Jan 12 10:21:42 2022 (Elapsed Time: 19.23 seconds)

It fails immediately after the "cracking features" step.

From the results window:

> ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
>
> The table was not found.
>
> The table was not found.[NHDFlowline_Clip1]
>
> The table was not found.
>
> The table was not found. [NHDFlowline_Clip1]
>
> Invalid Topology [M coord limit exceeded.]
>
> Failed to execute (Clip).
>
> ...(Elapsed time: 19.23 seconds)

Any suggestions on how to fix?

Answer (score 1):

Still not sure what was causing the error, but I created a blank map with just three layers - the ortho, line feature and tax map. Extracted the necessary tax parcel again, and ran the clip, which worked.

Comment: Upon further reading, it seems that the Error 999999 may have been caused by small segments present in a previously completed clip. This was due to the fact that the stream ran close to the property line and crossed it back and forth several times, so the clip created tiny line segments. By starting a new map, and re-adding the full source layers this issue was avoided.